# android: how to setSelection the spinner from recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-spinner

I have Spinner and a RecyclerView. I could scroll the recyclerview from the spinners setOnItemSelectedListener by mLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(position);

But how to achieve the reverse. If i scroll the RecyclerView I want the spinner also change. I dont have access to spinner.setSelection within the recyclerviewer.

Comment: Can take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html)

Comment: found the perfect answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878132/snaphelper-item-position