# How to scroll only one item by one in recyclerview?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, swipe

I have a horizontal list which it's using a recycler view  and a PagerSnapHelper to simulate a view pager.
I want to swipe scroll one element at the time, but the problem is that i can scroll to the last element with one swipe.

So my problem is that I want to stop the swipe after one element swiped so if someone has any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Hello :) Can you post your activity/fragment and xml code?

Comment: Hi
Could you please add Piece of code to look in how you have implemented ?

Comment: Why don't you just use `ViewPager`?

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding a logic by checking the current position as mentioned in below post:

[SnapHelper Item Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878132/snaphelper-item-position)

```
  public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                View centerView = snapHelper.findSnapView(mLayoutManager);
                int pos = mLayoutManager.getPosition(centerView);
                Log.e("Snapped Item Position:",""+pos);
            }
        }
```

or Something like this:

```
LinearSnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper() {
    @Override
    public int findTargetSnapPosition(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager, int velocityX, int velocityY) {
        View centerView = findSnapView(layoutManager);
        if (centerView == null) 
            return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;

        int position = layoutManager.getPosition(centerView);
        int targetPosition = -1;
        if (layoutManager.canScrollHorizontally()) {
            if (velocityX < 0) {
                targetPosition = position - 1;
            } else {
                targetPosition = position + 1;
            }
        }

        if (layoutManager.canScrollVertically()) {
            if (velocityY < 0) {
                targetPosition = position - 1;
            } else {
                targetPosition = position + 1;
            }
        }

        final int firstItem = 0;
        final int lastItem = layoutManager.getItemCount() - 1;
        targetPosition = Math.min(lastItem, Math.max(targetPosition, firstItem));
        return targetPosition;
    }
};
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Ref: https://ogeek.cn/qa/?qa=441913/&show=441914